# Use VBA ActiveX Command Button to print into first empty row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a Command Button which is on Sheet 1 to print a value (for now, just using "now" as a dummy value) on the first empty row in column B on a second Sheet - Sheet 2, which has been renamed "Log". Something is not working in the code - I've tried:

```
Worksheets("Log").Activate
```

Which worked to activate that second sheet, but it printed the value in the first empty row on *Sheet 1!*

My current code (in full) is as follows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Log")
With ws
   Dim emptyrow As Long
   Dim LastRow As Variant

      emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
      LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value

        If IsNumeric(LastRow) Then
        Else
            LastRow = 0
        End If

        Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = LastRow + 1 'I want to print an ascending count of the scenarios I have printed
        Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = Now 'This should print the time and date
End With
```

For some reason, this still prints the value for "LastRow + 1" and "Now" in Sheet 1 in cells B2 and B3, respectively.

Comment: `.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value `  Looking at it, your `lastrow` will be the same.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that was the problem. Thank you!! How can I accept your comment as an answer so you get the credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub PasteDataOnEmptyRow()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Set ws = Worksheets("Log")
 With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row ' Last row keeping values in column A:A

    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = LastRow + 1 'This will print in column B:B (last empty row of A:A)
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = Now 'This will print in column C:C (last empty row of A:A)
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = "Test in A:A last row"
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Test in A:A the following row"
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your object `ws`

So

`.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value` in your with block,

Looking at it, your `lastrow` will be the same.